# Add not supported php function to symfony project

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use `array_column` (php5.4) but I figured out that it's supported as of php5.5.

So I added a new file which I called `functions.php`:

```
<?php
if (! function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column(array $input, $columnKey, $indexKey = null) {
        .....
    }
}
```

And I included it into my controller where I needed it.

So my question is what'd be the right way to add my `functions.php` to a symfony project?

Comment: maybe you could create a service where you check if you can use array_column

Comment: You can add the class to the `autoload.files` part of your composer.json like https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/blob/master/src/Php55/composer.json#L24. The easiest way, by far, would be to use the `symfony/polyfill-php55` package (as linked to for the composer.json example) as it would require absolutely no upkeep for you.

Comment: @qooplmao the `composer.json` is indeed very elegant +1 thx